# Not able to initialize the hidden fields in django

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my view:

```
def my_view(request):

if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyForm(initial={'user': "my_user"})

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = MyForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        print("form is valid")

else:
    form = MyForm()

return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is the form

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    my_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    user = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()

        my_field = cleaned_data.get('my_field')

        if not my_field:
            raise forms.ValidationError('error')
```

Nothing is printed on the console (`print("form is valid")`), so the form is not valid, and this problem comes from the hidden field.

When I work without the hidden fields, the form is valid

What's wrong with my code ? How to initialize the values of hidden fields from the view function (or another way to do it without including it in the HTML) ?

Comment: You did not return the `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was not really related to my view or form class but to the template. So I am posting this if anyone missed it out: Don't forget to include the hidden fields in the form:

```
{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden_field }}
{% endfor %}
```